# Searching for a SQL Value from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given a list of product numbers:

```
  12-A-01234-1
```

However these values are stored in the table as:

```
  12A012341
```

Is there a way to query in SQL without manually removing all the dashes from the list?

Basically I want to query:

```
select * from product.product
where productnumber in (*list of product numbers*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do this :

```
select * 
from product.product
where productnumber in (
   select replace(prodnumbers, '-','') 
   from values ('12-A-01234-1' , '12-A-01234-2' , ...) t(prodnumbers)
)
```

Comment: for Pete's sake, that's exactly what I was trying to do but I was trying to add the "-" to my side instead of removing them from the list... its always the simplest solutions that evade me.